# GPU computing: how much VRAM do I need for mini batch gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, nvidia, gpu

I want to do some GPU computing with an NVIDIA card, and am deciding between having a GTX 960 with a 2GB or 4GB ram. Which one should I take? How much difference would these make in terms of the batch size I can use for mini batch gradient descent? Would this difference be significant?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most costly operations is coping data to/from the GPU device. Therefore, if you anticipate working with datasets >2GB, the larger mem will be of great benefit. You could either store large chunks of data (some multiple of minibatch size) at a time, and/or possibly store the entire heldout dataset if frequent evaluation is necessary. Of course, you could always use async copy to/from gpu (if device supports it) or other [optimizations](https://www.microway.com/hpc-tech-tips/optimize-cuda-host-to-device-transfers/) and certainly do fine with the smaller mem; however, this adds some additional complexity and any toolkits you use (if applicable) may not take advantage of this feature.